# Signed, Accepted And Emailed back Job Offer Contract: No Confirmation Back

Tags: professionalism, job-offer, email

I have received a job offer via email. The email contained a formal contract of employment signed by the owner of the company. I have accepted the offer; ie, signed it, scanned it and sent it back as an attachment to my email. The email confirms I have accepted the offer and thanked them, etc..

I haven't received a confirmation that the email was received (I was silly and didn't place  a Delivery Status Notification on the email). It's been almost 24 hours. My email communication has been with the HR/Secretary all throughout the process and thats who I emailed the acceptance and contract to. The job position is Software Engineer.

Do you think its worthwhile emailing them to confirm the email was received etc? I dont want to sound pestering but then again I dont want to turn up in 3 weeks and say "I'm here to start" and they are like "You never got back to us?". Any advice on wording this email? Should it be a long winded formal email or a simple one line "Hi X, just confirming you received my email and attachments?"?

Comment: I don't think the "Delivery status" would have helped you at all - I would wait 3-4 business days and then call to follow up (I tend to alternate to other communication mediums if one hasn't succeeded) - I would phrase it as "I would like to check the status of my application/acceptance of position X, I have e-mailed you my confirmation on (date Y), and would like to know the next steps as to how to proceed". Did your offer have a clear start date? [This](http://www.artofmanliness.com/2012/03/01/how-to-write-an-email-that-will-actually-get-a-response/) may help as well.

Comment: On the contrary, you would have been silly to place the Delivery Confirmation request on the email.

Answer (score 7):

Don't send another email. Get on the phone. Chasing an email that has gone without a response with another email is going to leave you in exactly the same place - waiting on a reply to an email.

Phone up the person you sent the email to and just ask if it arrived OK, the attachments were intact, if the scanned signature is OK, etc.

If you don't have their phone number, call the company's main phone number and ask for them by name.

Comment: This is also a good time to ask what the next steps are, or what else you need to do prior to your start date.

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow up within the next 24 hours: say that you are in the sanity check phase and you are making sure that they know you emailed your acceptance earlier and that if they have any questions, need any clarifications or have further requests, to contact you immediately. Say that you are extremely pleased with the hiring process and that you are eager to know your start date.